# [android]What conditions do I need to have a virtual device the same as the actual device?

Tags: android, device, android-virtual-device

Resolution ,
dpi(hdpi, xhdpi...etc) ,
device's inch.. what else

I'm using genymotion and I need more devices than there.
so I'm trying to edit resolution or dpi..

In addition, What conditions do i need to have a virtual device the same as the actual device?
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Adding a custom virtual device

If you cannot find the virtual device you need, you can select a customizable phone or tablet from the available ones:

```
Custom Phone - 4.1.1 - API 16 - 768x1280;
Custom Phone - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 768x1280;
Custom Phone - 4.3 - API 18 - 768x1280;
Custom Phone - 4.4.4 - API 19 - 768x1280;
Custom Tablet - 4.1.1 - API 16 - `2560x1600`;
Custom Tablet - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 2560x1600;
Custom Tablet - 4.3 - API 18 - 2560x1600;
Custom Tablet - 4.4.4 - API 19 - `2560x1600`.
```

Once you have deployed one of those virtual devices, you can edit the RAM, screen size and density from the Configuration menu by clicking .

For more information about configuring virtual devices, please refer to section [Configuring a virtual device.](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/#Configuring_a_virtual_device)